# .NET documentation api

Tags: .net, documentation

Is there any way to get .NET class methods with documentation? For example some API, that takes .NET version and class name and returns content for its methods like in [tables on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0#methods)

I need to implement some strange kind of intellisense for .NET so I'm looking for ways to get original documentation of static methods for some classes.

Preferred way — get documentation from JS code. Using reflection in C# — only as a last resort.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Are you looking for something like Swagger?

Comment: Reflection doesn't work, since the assembly metadata doesn't contain the documentation. But you can of course parse the XML file that lies next to the dll (if it was generated)

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary, nope, I am not looking for swagger. I am looking for documentation of default .NET classes, for example all methods of "System.String"

Comment: Ah you are looking for a potential API behind the MSDN docs that provide you with the Microsoft provided documentation of .NET methods etc.?

Comment: Yes, something, that will give me the official documentation (the same, which you see in any IDE when codding for .NET)